# How can I delete row in one table acordding to another query?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table that has 3 fields:

1. Case number
2. Code item
3. amount

I created a query that retrieves data from another table. The query also has 3 fields. The same 3 as the table.

I want to delete the records from the table that are in the query.
In the table, the Case number and the Code item are P-keys.

When I tried to build the deletion query I got an error message saying that Access doesn't know from which table he needs to delete.

I don't know well VB so I prefer the solution to be as simple in VB as possible.

Comment: In other databases with standard sql it would look like this: 'delete from table_name where ("Case number", "Code item", "amount") in (your_select)`. Maybe you can try, if that works the same way in Access. But I know, that Microsoft did a good job to make Access not completely compliant to the standard (as they often did also with other solutions in the past).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that your table and query might have the same name. If so, try changing the name of the query. A simple, common naming scheme I use is as follows:

**Table:** "TableName"

**Query:** "TableNameQuery"

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my table and my query have different names so this isn't the problem.

Comment: I bulid this query by Query Designe and not by code. I dont have much knowleged in SQL, but if it's not complicated I can try.

Comment: Ok, so let's look at the SQL code of the query in question. Open the query in design mode (right click on the query > design mode). The in the Access ribbon, click Design > View > SQL View. This might help us figure out what's wrong.